# Getting full native language name in Craft 3 language switcher

Tags: craft3, localization, language

I'm porting across a multilingual project from Craft2 to Craft3 and have to rebuild the language switcher. I was previously using the `.nativeName` method but apparently this is deprecated. I've got a really basic one working for flipping between the English and French versions of my site :

```
{% set langSwitcher = craft.app.sites.getAllSites() %}

{% for lang in langSwitcher %}
   {# Get base URL #}
   {% set url = alias(lang.baseUrl) %}
   <a href="{{url}}">{{ lang.language }}</a>
{% endfor %}
```

The `{{ lang.language }}` is outputting `en` & `fr` but how do I get it to display the full native language names i.e `English` & `Francais`?

I found the `getDisplayName()` function in the docs but can't seem to get it working properly: https://docs.craftcms.com/api/v3/craft-i18n-locale.html#public-methods

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [`site.language`](http://awseb-e-f-awsebloa-1f9jh1rryyr2z-94257389.us-west-2.elb.amazonaws.com/api/v3/craft-models-site.html#property-language) attribute is just a string, i.e. the language code or locale ID, e.g. `'en'`.

To get the native name you'll need to go through the [`I18N` service](https://docs.craftcms.com/api/v3/craft-i18n-i18n.html) to pull the actual [Locale](https://docs.craftcms.com/api/v3/craft-i18n-locale.html) object via that locale ID:

```
{% set locale = craft.app.i18n.getLocaleById(lang.language) %}
<a href="{{url}}">{{ locale.nativeName }}</a>
```

**Edit:** As @Dr_Codswallop mentions in the comments, `locale.nativeName` is deprecated in Craft 3, and will be removed completely in Craft 4. `locale.displayName` should be used instead.

Comment: Thankyou Mats! I'd tried that technique but didn't realise `getLocaleByID()` accepted a string, I thought anything `getxxxById` required integers. My mistake.

Comment: If it helps anyone else on Craft3, `locale.nativeName` will work for now but is deprecated. Use `locale.displayName` instead.

Comment: You're completely right, @Dr_Codswallop – thanks! And yeah, I agree that the `getLocaleById()` method name is a bit misleading/unconventional. Usually in Craft, "ID" refers to a unique (integer) ID. You should put in a feature request that they rename the method to `getLocaleByCode` or something similar :P